# Installation is failed

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, python, dpkg

My Operating system is Ubuntu 20.04. To uninstall python 3.8, I have removed its files in my laptop. Now, I can not install any packages as I face this error:

```
sudo apt-get install xfonts-base
ReadIng package lists .... Done 
Bullding dependency tree Reading state Information ... Done 
sfonts-base ls already the newest version (1: 1.0.5). 
O upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.  1 not fully installed or removed.  After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used. 
you want to continue?  [Y / n] y 
Setting up python3.8-minimal (3.8.10-0ubuntui "20.10.1) ... 
Could not find platform independent libraries <pref ix> 
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix> Consider setting SPYTHONHOME to  <prefix>[: <exec_pref ix>]
Python path configuration:
PYTHONHOME * PYTHONPATH = (not set) program name= "/usr/bin/python3.8"
isolated = 0 
environment =0
User site =1
import site = 0
sys.  base executable ="/usr/bin/python3.8"
sys.base prefix = / usr 
sys.base exec_pref ix =,' / usr sys.Executable = '/usr/bin/python3.8' Sys.prefix= 'usr'
sys.exec_prefix = '/usr'
sys.path = L "/usr/lib/python38.zip'," /usr/lib/python3.8, '/ usr / lib / lib-dynload ",
]
'Fatal Python init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding 
Python runt in the state:  core initialized 
ModulellotFoundError: No module named 'encodings' 
Cunnent thread 0x00007f8c7dc98740 (most recent call first): 
no Python frame> dpkg: enror processing package pythona.8-minimal (--configure): -Installed pythons.8-minimal package post-  installat ion script subprocess returned error exit status 1 
Enrors uere encountered uhile pracessing: pythons.8-minimal 
E: Sub-process / usr / bin / dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Does anybody know how can I fix it?
Thanks

Comment: reinstall the os?

Comment: Messing with python is a very common way of destroying your system.

Comment: Never remove the default python version in Ubuntu. Now you will have to reinstall. You can install other versions of python, though. For example, you can `sudo apt install python3.9`, and later run it with the command `python3.9`

Comment: You killed the OS re install.

Comment: @Archisman Panigrahi: I couldnot install any package. I faced the error  as mentioned above.

Comment: @Khorshid After messing up with the default python version, your only option is to reinstall Ubuntu. The command I wrote in the previous comment is for installing another version of python in a working system.